# Создание N списков

Tags: python, list

Необходимо создать N пустых списков.  Думал, что может можно сделать через for, но столкнулся с проблемой в назывании переменной: нельзя просто добавить к названию переменной аргумент цикла. Как это можно сделать и можно ли это сделать не через цикл, а проще?

Comment: `[[] for i in range(n)]`?

Comment: entithat, как вариант, но я имел ввиду другое. Мне нужно создать N списков: a1 = [], a2 = [], a3 = [], aN = []

Comment: Вы уверены, что Вам нужно `N` переменных-списков? Не разумнее ли использовать список списков? Тогда к `i`-му списку можно будет обращаться как `a[i]`, а не `ai`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    exec('a{} = []'.format(i))
```

Либо:

```
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    globals()['a{}'.format(i)] = []
```

Либо использовать словарь.